# How can I use OCX in console without System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#, winapi, com, winui-3, ocx

I tried many things to use OCX in WinUI3, but there was no way possible, and I tried to find executable code in the console, but there was only one way using System.Windows.Forms. Since System.Windows.Forms is not available in WinUI3, I tried the code below using Win32 API.

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
    public static extern object CoCreateInstance([In] ref Guid clsid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkOuter, int context, [In] ref Guid iid);

    static void Main()
    {
        var guid1 = new Guid("A1574A0D-6BFA-4BD7-9020-DED88711818D");
        var guid2 = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");

        var a = CoCreateInstance(ref guid1, null, 1, ref guid2);

        var b = a as KHOpenAPILib.KHOpenAPI; // KHOpenAPILib.KHOpenAPI is an interface on the dll automatically created by the visual studio with tlbimp when adding com references.
        b.CommConnect(); // E_UNEXPECTED
    }
}
```

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var guid1 = new Guid("A1574A0D-6BFA-4BD7-9020-DED88711818D");
        var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(guid1);
        var a = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var b = a as KHOpenAPILib.KHOpenAPI;
        b.CommConnect(); // E_UNEXPECTED
    }
}
```

However, as written in the annotation, E_UNEXPECTED occurs. Can you tell me the cause or any other way?

Even if I try the code below considering STA, the result is the same.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Foo);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add STAThread attribute to Main https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2232?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#example

Comment: @SimonMourier The same result comes out. Also, I think it's the same effect as the third code.

Comment: No, in your 3rd code, you create another thread. Have you tried it?

Comment: @SimonMourier I applied it to the Main of all three codes, and the results were the same.

Comment: The most natural code is the 2nd. It should work with STAThread applied on Main(). If it doesn't it's more an issue with the component itself (if you do have a "b" reference). E_UNEXPECTED is a very generic COM error that doesn't say much, you should contact the component vendor/provider.

Comment: How exactly do you use the OCX in WinForms?  How do you instantiate it, initialize, etc?

Comment: @Nick Hosting OCX using AxHost from WinForms works fine, but there is no example of initializing without AxHost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, and it is not related to WinUI.  Using OCXs takes more than just calling CoCreateInstance.  Please look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.axhost?view=windowsdesktop-7.0. Try creating such a class yourself following the examples.  I cannot be more specific, because I don't have access to your OCX.